# Django - getting two entries in the database, one with null and other with all data captured

Tags: django, sql-update

I have a form and am updating the database with the form entries. I see that there are two rows getting updated one with NULL entries and other with all data. There is something wrong in my view but I don't know what, please help.

models.py

```py
class Metadataform(models.Model):


    Models = models.CharField(max_length=5000, blank=True)
    Device = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    Document = models.FileField(upload_to='')
```

views.py

```py
def submission(request):


        Models = request.POST["Models"]
        Device = request.POST["Device"]

        Error_Estimation = request.POST["Error_Estimation"]


        if request.method == 'POST':
                form = Fileuploadform(request.POST, request.FILES)
                if form.is_valid():
                        form.save()
                        newdoc = Metadataform(Document = 
                        request.FILES['Document'])
                        newdoc.save()

                        return render(request, "home.html")

        else:
                form = Fileuploadform()
```

There are two-row entries in the database. 1 row with NULL entries and the uploaded file link, another row with all the data and the file link

Comment: remove: newdoc = Metadataform(Document = 
                        request.FILES['Document'])
                        newdoc.save()

Comment: @sandeep how can you assert this is the issue without even knowing what the missing parts of the code are doing ?

Comment: @user11603936 please post a proper [mcve] - or even better, do the official Django tutorial, read the official Django documention about forms, modelforms and models filefield, then you should be able to find out why your code is broken.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, form.save() is saving all fields including file field. newdoc.save() is creating new instance and saving the file but no data for other fields. I think solution worked, comment has been upvoted.

Comment: @sandeep I know how a Django form works, thanks. The point here is that the OP uses some `Fileuploadform` which is nowhere in the code snippet, so we just can NOT know what happens. Your "solution" is a wild guess at best, which may seem to cure the issue (and possibly really solve it) but doesn't explain anything about the issue and doesn't allow the OP nor anyone else reading this to learn anything either. This is typically the "programming by accident" (aka "programming by permutation") anti-pattern, and SO's goal is definitly NOT to promote such anti-patterns.

Comment: @sandeep...thanks, that was all i needed to fix.